# Error while uploading image and JSON object from Angular to Spring Boot

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I am using Angular 8 and spring boot. If I upload image and object from Postman, it successfully uploads. If I try the same from Angular it fails and error is

```
[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported]
```

If I set headers to following in Angular

```
var options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8') };
    return this.http.patch(`${environment.apiUrl}products/`, data, options);
```

I still get the error

```
[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

Here is the controller in Spring Boot

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(
            @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
            @RequestPart(value = "product") @Valid ProductDTO productDTO) throws IOException
```

In Angular this is file upload input

```
<input type="file" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" accept="image/*">
```

In component

```
fileToUpload: File = null;
```

This is file upload function

```
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
}
```

In Submit method

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload);
    formData.append('product', this.form.value);
```

This is all happening in Angular and Spring, but in Postman it is successfully updating.

In Postman
[image]

Comment: please show what content type  you are using in your headers in postman

Comment: This is it. multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>

Comment: As @emmanuelagarry suggests you, maybe the error is in the content-type of your header.

Comment: If I set to`multipart/form-data`, I receive error `Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005436/the-request-was-rejected-because-no-multipart-boundary-was-found-in-springboot

Comment: @rw026 In the answer you suggested, If I leave it blank, It sets the headers to `application/octet-stream` automatically. No luck

Comment: Try changing your angular request from patch to post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61389255/upload-files-angular-spring-boot/61428407#61428407 worked form